# Android; How can I detect whether a Parent activity is still alive in Activity stack and then receate it

Tags: android

I have activities in sequence as Activity A calling Activity B,When I am on Activity B I press Home button and start another Application (for example Map). If i stay on this second application for a long time say 5-10 minutes and then press Home Button again and choose to Start my application again, then Activity B is started again and works fine. But when i Press Back key  - I return to my Activity A again (which is also correct) but it shows a Blank Screen. Ideally in correct version it should show me Acitivty A with the XML data is ListView form.

Alternatively, in the above description, when the other Map Application is started and if the user stay on it only for 1-2 minutes then the above problem doesnt not occur.

Can anyone suggest a solution on the same.
Is it that i need to check in Activity B whether Activity A is still there in Activity Stack (How do i do the same) and If its not in my Activity stack then re-create it.

I tried doing alwaysRetainTaskstate in my Android manifest file for Activity A. But it doesnt work at all

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any of that, Android takes care of the technicalities for you - it will recreate your Activity A.

You just need to remember to save A's state when B is opened (take a look at `Activity.onSaveInstanceState`). When A is restarted, your saved state will be passed to `onCreate`.

You should really read about [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/activity-launch-mode-in-android.html) should help.